# ¿Cómo iterar sobre las claves de un diccionario y obtener su "índice"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, diccionarios

Quiero hacer una función que itere sobre todos las `keys` de un diccionario en especifico, luego que retorne le "índice" (por así decirlo). Esta es mi idea de como debería ser:

```
def dictIndex(arg0,arg1):
    for x in range(len(arg1.keys())):
        if arg0 == arg1.keys()[x]:
            return x
```

Cuando la llamo el código, y ejecuto por consola me da el siguiente error:

```
File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\ok.py", line 19, in dictIndex
    if arg0 == arg1.keys()[x]:
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

Mi pregunta es, **¿Como solucioneo ese error o hay alguna otra manera alternativa de hacer lo que quiero?** A continuación adjunto el código completo, para ser más especifico:

```
diccionario = {
    "nombre" : "Gabriel",
    "edad" : 14,
    "pythonlover": True
}

def dictIndex(arg0,arg1):
    for x in range(len(arg1.keys())):
        if arg0 == arg1.keys()[x]:
            return x 

print(dictIndex("nombre",diccionario))
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los diccionarios no tienen índice, no son objetos indizables, se implementan mediante tablas hash dónde la función de "índice" la hace la clave (el hash de la clave).

**Hasta Python 3.7 <sup>[*]</sup> los diccionarios no mantenían el orden de inserción de las parejas clave-valor**, al igual que los conjuntos (`set`) eran contenedores desordenados por naturaleza. Ésto significaba que cada vez que se iteraba o se usaban sus vistas (`dict.keys`, `dict.items`, `dict.values`), el orden de sus items no tenía por qué ser el mismo, de hecho, era indeterminado. A Partir de Python 3.7, el orden de inserción se mantiene cómo característica del lenguaje. Por lo tanto, **lo que pretendes solo tiene sentido en Python >= 3.7 o en versiones anteriores usando `collections.OrderedDict`**

Para conseguirlo puedes usar `enumerate`:

```
def dict_index(value, dicc):
    for i, key in enumerate(dicc):
        if value == key:
            return i
```

El error en tu código es asumir que la **vista** retornada por `dict.keys` es indizable, no lo es. Podrías generar una lista o tupla con las claves, pero es más ineficiente y complejo que usar `enumerate`:

```
def dict_index(value, dicc):
    keys = tuple(dicc)  # Lo mismo que tuple(dicc.keys())
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        if value == keys[i]:
            return i
```

---

**<sup>[*]</sup>** La reimplementación  de los diccionarios en CPython se llevó a cabo realmente en Python 3.6, el objetivo fue buscar un incremento considerable de eficiencia, no que mantuvieran el orden. El que mantuvieran el orden se consideraba un efecto colateral de la nueva implementación nada más, por tanto susceptible de cambiar en el futuro.

A raíz de una [consulta en las mailing lists de Python](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151286.html) sobre hacer de ésto una característica del lenguaje, el propio Guido van Rossum contestó literalmente:

> Make it so. "Dict keeps insertion order" is the ruling. Thanks!

por lo que el orden de inserción se mantendría en los diccionarios como característica del lenguaje a partir de Python 3.7.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hágase, dijo el _Benevolent Dictator for Life_, y se hizo. Gran explicación tanto de código como histórica

Answer (score 0):

La lógica de tu código tiene sentido, pero Python no lo entiende porque lo que te retorna el .keys() no es una lista como tal. Se ve como una lista pero no lo es. Por lo que simplemente puedes convertirla en una lista, como se muestra a continuación:

```
def dictIndex(arg0,arg1):
    for x in range(len(arg1.keys())):
        if arg0 == list(arg1.keys())[x]:
            return x 

print(dictIndex("nombre",diccionario))
```

En sí, este es un método no tan bien optimizado. Lo que yo haría sería algo así:

```
def dictIndex(llave,dicc):
    lista=list(dicc.keys())     #Una lista con los valores que retorna .keys()
    return lista.index(llave)   #Retornar el indice donde se encuentre llave

print(dictIndex('pythonlover',diccionario))
```

Como ves, creo una lista con los valores de `.keys()` y retorno el índice donde se encuentra lo que ingresé a `llave` (en este caso `'pythonlover'`)

#### Extra:

También, puedes eliminar la variable `lista` y colocarla directamente en el **`return`**. Con el fin de ahorrarte una línea de código. Esto, tal vez, puede generar que una persona que no tenga tantos conocimientos del lenguaje, no entienda el código. Pero te lo dejo a tu criterio.

```
def dictIndex(llave,dicc):
    return list(dicc.keys()).index(llave)
```

En fin, de esa manera, el código queda más compacto.