# Recorrer un diccionario dentro de un diccionario en python

Tags: python

cree un código simulando la puntuación de notas a estudiantes y mi pregunta es si se puede recorrer un diccionario dentro de un diccionario. es decir dentro de todos los usuarios(1,2,3) recorrer las notas de los mismos para después sacar una nota promedio. Pude lograrlo pero de otra manera distinta.
La idea es tal vez hacerlo con un ¿for?No tengo idea si se podrá hacer de esa forma

```
students = {

    "1" :{
        "nombre": "Valentin",
        "apellido": "Blanco",
        "nota": " "
    },
        
    "2" :{
        "nombre": "Lolo",
        "apellido": "Gutierrez",
        "nota": " "
    },
        
    "3" :{
        "nombre": "Juanito",
        "apellido": "Montana",
        "nota": " "
    }
} 


contador = len(students.keys())
aprobados = list([])
suspendidos= list([])

stud = input("Ingrese el estudiante: ")
new_Nota = int(input("Ingrese la nota del estudiante: "))
acumulador = 0 
while (contador > 0):
    if (stud not in students.keys()):
        print("Estudiante inexistente")
    if (stud in students.keys()):
        contador -= 1
        acum += new_Nota
        students[stud]["nota"] = new_Nota
        if (new_Nota <= 7):
            suspendidos.append([stud])
        elif (new_Nota >= 6):
            aprobados.append([stud])
    if (contador == 0):
        break
    stud = input("Ingrese el estudiante: ")
    new_Nota= int(input("Ingrese la nota del estudiante: "))
    


print("Aprobados:",aprobados)
print("Suspendidos:",suspendidos)    
print("El promedio de las notas es ", acumulador/len(students.keys()))
```

Comment: En Python no se usan paréntesis para el control de flujo.

Comment: Si se puede debes iterar sobre los elementos que retornasn `keys()`, `values()` o `items()`, pero hacer las comparaciones directamente con el valor. Te puede servir [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365738/c%c3%b3mo-iterar-sobre-las-claves-de-un-diccionario-y-obtener-su-%c3%adndice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas cosas que puedes hacer para mejorar ese código. Para empezar, la estructura de datos. No es necesario etiquetar a cada alumno con un número. Además, las notas pueden estar especificadas como una lista para la que será fácil obtener el promedio ya que para una lista de notas el promedio sera `sum(lista_notas) / len(lista_notas)`. Entonces será mejor especificar la estructura de datos de la forma:

```
students = [
    {
       'nombre': 'Valentin',
       'apellido': 'Blanco',
       'notas': [8, 10, 6, 9]
    }, 
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Asi tienes una lista de alumnos, donde cada alumno es un diccionario (tienes que entender un diccionario como un fomulario de datos). De esta forma cada alumno tiene un id de posición en la lista y las notas del primer alumno estarán disponibles de la forma `students[0]['notas']`. Asi que si quiero las notas del alumno *n* solo habrá que ajustar la instrucción anterior:

```
idx = int(input("Ingrese el alumno del que quiere obtener el promedio: "))
alumno = student[idx-1]
promedio = sum(alumno['notas'] / len(alumno['notas'])
```

Adjuntar los promedios en una lista para luego contar cuantos aprobados o desaprobados ahora resulta fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar iterar de la siguiente manera:

```
suma_notas = 0
# En el "for" sumas todas las notas
for usuario, dict2 in students.items():
    suma_notas += int(dict2["nota"])
promedio = suma_notas/len(students)
```